# GAME- SOS Board Game , SOS Sequence and Score Update not working

Tags: java, android

After any SOS Sequence, My code is not work properly.Automatically puts S and I can not put any O character and scores updated undesirably.Is there any idea for solving my problem?
You can see my one part of codes.

```
public void onClick (View view) {

        if (player1turn) {
            ((Button) view).setText("S");
            view.setEnabled( false );

        } else {
            ((Button) view).setText("O");
            view.setEnabled( false );

        }

        roundcount++;
        checkForWin();
    if(checkForWin()) {
        if (player1turn) {
            player1Wins();

        } else {
            player2Wins();

        }
    }else if (roundcount == 49){
        draw();
    }else {
        player1turn=!player1turn;

    }

}
private boolean checkForWin(){         
        String[][] field = new String[7][7];    
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                field[i][j]=buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }
    //Comparing the Fields(Columns)

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

            if (field[i][0].contains(("S")) && field[i][1].contains("O")
                    && field[i][2].contains("S")
                    && !field[i][0].equals(""))
            {
                roundcount+=1;
                player1score.setText( ""+roundcount );
                return true;
            }
```

[Start Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m8Ls.png)

[1st SOS Sequence and Score Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGooN.jpg)

[Automatically puts S and automatically score update when click any button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GICC7.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: any SOS sequence(Vertical , horizantal , diagonal) then I can not make any SOS sequence.Allows just one times and then when I clicked, just puts S character so doesn.'t work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (field[i][0].equals("S") && field[i][1].equals("O") && field[i][2].equals("S")) { roundcount+=1; player1score.setText( ""+roundcount ); return true; }
```

try like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){ for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){ if (field[i][j].equals("S") && field[i][j].equals("O") && field[i][j].equals("S")) { roundcount+=1; player1score.setText( ""+roundcount ); return true; }} }
```